# sink() while simultaneously show ouput in console

Tags: r, sink

How can I redirect output to some txt file but in such a way so that i can see that output simultaneously in console while generating step by step?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the `split=TRUE` argument of `sink`:

```
sink(file="myfile",split=TRUE)
```